# Syntax error when using structs in cilk

Tags: cilk

I've been getting an odd syntax error when trying to compile my cilk program. Maybe I'm missing something basic that is a quirk of cilk. Whenever I use structs (as in the code below) the program produces a syntax error. This error doesn't occur when I take out the cilk keywords and compile+run the program normally.

Some other notes that might give some insight are that it compiles fine if I don't try to assign to any of the variables (like size) in the struct, the error always shows up for the line number below the struct lines, but it doesn't matter what that particular line is, and as I mentioned before, it compiles just fine when the struct aspect is taken out.

```
typedef struct StackStruct{
        int size;
        Link *head;
        Link *tail;
        Link *prev;
} Stack;


cilk void Iter_tsp(Tour *tour){
        Stack *my_stack = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
        my_stack->size = 1;
        ....
}
```